# How to join two datatables into one ? asp.net vb or c#

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, join, merge, datatable

actual problem seems a bit complicated than the Title says .. but hope someone can figure it out ..

I have two datatables which I intends to bind them to Gridview. But I need bit of the first dt and bit from second dt.

Second table has only one row that represents to every row in the same column in first table.

There is no primary key or relationship between two tables though.

Hope my explanation is cleared enough .. Thanks alot ... looking forward to have a solution soon,.

For example,

[image]

I tried datatable.merge though. Didn't produce the last table i want.

Comment: Laurence, it's more an SQL question than a .NET one. You could join those two tables in a stored procedure or raw SQL to produce the necessary resultset for your grid. How do you access your data in your code?

Comment: yes. two datatables came from tow stored procedure but in my organisation, database job is handled by db person and it's hard to chase them around so i am trying to do it myself in .net side. is there a way to do it in .net side or i have to refer it back for db job ? thanks ...

Comment: Can you use LINQ? There are plenty of examples on how to join different datatables on this site and also MSDN (e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921.aspx). Otherwise, you can still try the datatable merge: DataTable fullTable= table1.Copy(); fullTable.Merge(table2);  but only show the columns you want in your GridView.

Comment: Thanks Andrei ... I will try to use Linq  or if i can't i will try Eval with variables as the second table contains just one row. Good Day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this link

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/adodotnetdataset/thread/ecb6a83d-b9b0-4e64-8107-1ca8757fe58c

either do it using linq or by putting all the tables in a dataset creating pk/fk on the data tables  and joining them that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
  ''' <summary>
  ''' Merge two datatables that have a 1:1 relationship
  ''' </summary>
  ''' <param name="dtb1">Required Datatable.</param>
  ''' <param name="dtb2">Required Datatable.</param>
  ''' <param name="dtb1MatchField">Required String. Field name in dtb1 to use to match records</param>
  ''' <param name="dtb2MatchField">Required String. Field name in dtb2 to use to match records</param>
  ''' <remarks></remarks>
  Private Function MergeDataTables(ByVal dtb1 As DataTable, ByVal dtb2 As DataTable, ByVal dtb1MatchField As String, ByVal dtb2MatchField As String) As DataTable
    Dim dtbOutput As DataTable = dtb1.Copy
    Dim lstSkipFields As New List(Of String)
    For Each dcl As DataColumn In dtb2.Columns
      Try
        dtbOutput.Columns.Add(dcl.ColumnName, dcl.DataType)
      Catch ex As DuplicateNameException
        lstSkipFields.Add(dcl.ColumnName)
      End Try
    Next dcl
    'Merge dtb2 records that match existing records in dtb1
    Dim dtb2Temp As DataTable = dtb2.Copy
    For int2 As Integer = dtb2Temp.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
      Dim drw2 As DataRow = dtb2Temp.Rows(int2)
      Dim o2 As Object = drw2(dtb2MatchField)
      For Each drw1 As DataRow In dtbOutput.Rows
        Dim o1 As Object = drw1(dtb1MatchField)
        If o1.ToString = o2.ToString Then
          For Each dcl As DataColumn In dtb2Temp.Columns
            If Not lstSkipFields.Contains(dcl.ColumnName) Then
              drw1(dcl.ColumnName) = drw2(dcl.ColumnName)
            End If
          Next dcl
          dtb2Temp.Rows.Remove(drw2)
        End If
      Next drw1
    Next int2
    'add rows that weren't in dtb1
    For Each drw2 As DataRow In dtb2Temp.Rows
      Dim drw1 As DataRow = dtbOutput.NewRow
      For Each dcl As DataColumn In dtb2Temp.Columns
        drw1(dcl.ColumnName) = drw2(dcl.ColumnName)
      Next dcl
      dtbOutput.Rows.Add(drw1)
    Next drw2
    Return dtbOutput
  End Function
```

Comment: Hi SSS ,, .. thanks for the help. Your answer looks great . but if I put in paras as in my example, MergeDataTables(dtTable1, dtTable2, Class, Class_Code) then it came out like this .. not like the result I wanted as in my example http://img176.imagevenue.com/img.php?image=368681970_Untitled_122_523lo.jpg ... I will try to tweak your code later on though. It seems like it doing a great job but probably you mis-understood my problem by a fraction.

Comment: You need to have a field to link the class (A1, A2) with the class_code (243). How do you know which class code class A1 has?

Comment: OH ... it is not like that Bro .. as in my example, the second table will just have one row ..... that will apply to every row in the first table .. you see, in the example, subject code 102 represents for all subjects .. it's wired but it is how it works in the system. As I said, there is no relationship between tables. We can only match by COLUMN name. Thanks for the help.

Comment: As in my example, there are columns with same name in the first table and second table ... we can match the column if column names are same in two tables .. and we can rename one of the column and apply both column in the result table ... that's what i was trying to do ..

Comment: Do the values in the single row ever change? If not just hardcode them in the SQL e.g. 
    SELECT *, '102' As Subject_code, '243' As Class_code FROM Students

Comment: OH it will change .. it depends on the parameter we pass in when calling stored procedure .. and both the first and second tables are returned relevantly so all we need to do is merge then together if we found same column names in the tables.